# How can I fetch specific nodes from XML using XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

**Given the following XML:**

```
<notes>
    <note>
        <to>Rove</to>
        <from>Jan</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
        <to>Joe</to>
        <from>Black</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
        <to>Wako</to>
        <from>Halo</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
        <to>Bill</to>
        <from>Job</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
</notes>
```

**Using XPath and C#, how can I get the following node set:**

> From {fromValue} To {toValue}
>
> From {fromValue} To {toValue}
>
> From {fromValue} To {toValue}
>
> From {fromValue} To {toValue}

**That what I tried so far:**

```
const string xmlStr =
                    @"<notes>
                        <note>
                           ......</notes>";



using (var stream = new StringReader(xmlStr))
{
    var document = new XPathDocument(stream);
    XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

    XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/notes/note/from");
    if (nodes.MoveNext())
    {
        XPathNavigator nodesNavigator = nodes.Current;

        XPathNodeIterator nodesText =
            nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);

        while (nodesText.MoveNext())
        {
           var currentValue = nodesText.Current.Value;
           Console.WriteLine("From: {0}, To: {1}", currentValue, currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**I get:**

```
From: Jan, To: Jan
From: Black, To: Black
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you're asking in C#, not necessarily involving XPath.

The simplest that comes to mind is

```
foreach (var node in XDocument.Parse(xmlStr).Root.Elements("note")) {
    Console.WriteLine("from: {0}; to: {1}",
                      node.Element("from").Value,
                      node.Element("to").Value);
}
```

This produces the output

```
from: Jan; to: Rove
from: Black; to: Joe
from: Halo; to: Wako
from: Job; to: Bill
```

Unless you are tied to .NET 2.0 (no `System.Xml.Linq`), or have some other requirement, I'd start with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML as elegant way to solve your issue.

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var xElements = document.Descendants("note");
foreach (var element in xElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "From {0} To {1}", 
        (string)element.Element("from"), 
        (string)element.Element("to"));
}
```